# Data extraction from online Json file

Tags: html, json, api

i have this Json file:
https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/

what i need is to display in my HTML file just the numbers in 4th quotation marks.
so instead of {"high": "197.96", "last": "173.32", "timestamp": "1382723663", "bid": "172.63", "volume": "33807.72470035", "low": "167.67", "ask": "173.32"} i need 173.32

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the JSON file in to a variable.

```
var json = (function () {
var json = null;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/",
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        json = data;
    }
});
return json;
})();
```

Then desired value can be read as follows.

json.last // This will contain your value.

You can also use $.getJSON which will be asynchronously in loading the file.

Comment: Cross-domain GET requests are not going to work without a proxy.